# About the notation <S,R> for ordered sets or <G,+> for groups. Is this notation absolutely rigorous or is it simply a convenient shortcut?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, soft-question, notation

One can often read things like: let (S,R) be an ordered set, that is the set S ordered by the relation R; or, let (G,+) be a group, that is a set G together with an operation verifying such and such properties.

This formulation is convenient, but is it absolutely rigorous?

*In this formulation, are the relation R or the operation + considered extensionally or intensionally?*

Officially, a relation or an operation are sets by themselves, sets of ordered pairs ( and even, sets of ordered pairs having an ordered pair as first element in the case of binary operations).

So the definition of a group as (G, +) would mean a group is an ordered pair of two sets.

Another problem : *(1) an ordered pair is not a set, since in a set there is no order. (2) if an ordered set is the ordered pair (S, R), then an ordered set is not a set.*

Last question: is there any formal manipulation that can be done with a symbol such as (S,R) or (G,+) ? I mean, *are there cases in which these symbols can be used in a formal reasoning*?

One case I can imagine is one in which we'd want to show that two groups are  identical. We could maybe prove  that (G, +) = (G', +') by showing that the two ordered pairs have the same first element and the same second element.

Comment: They are examples of [Mathematical structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure); see also [Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)#Definition).

Comment: Ordered pairs are usually defined as $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: "if an ordered set is the ordered pair (S, R), then an ordered set is not a set" What? An ordered pair *is* a set, via any of the usual formalizations (e.g. Kuratowski).

Comment: @ElliotG. So it's right to say that  : (Z,+) = {  {Z} , {Z,+} }. Is it the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although we often consider ordered pairing as "primitive," so that an ordered pair of sets is of different type than a single set, this isn't how things are actually implemented at the level of ZFC. There, [we implement ordered pairs of sets as sets themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory). There are many ways to do this, with in my experience the most common being $$\langle a,b\rangle=\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}.$$ It's easy to see under this definition that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ satisfies the key principle of ordered pair notions, namely that $$\langle a,b\rangle=\langle c,d\rangle\iff a=b\wedge c=d.$$ So this gives us a way to implement all the ordered pair language without going beyond sets.

Meanwhile, I'm not sure what your last question means, but I suspect the picture above will help clarify things.

---

EDIT: Addressing your edited last question, I think the answer is **no**. Set theory gives us a way of implementing mathematical objects which is very useful at the theory level but very useless at the practical level. In particular, we almost never care whether two groups are *identical*, only *isomorphic*; and the situations where we *do* care take place when both groups are already explicitly embedded in a larger domain which again we only care about up to isomorphism. For example, for a group $A$ the question "Is the group of inner automorphisms of $A$ the same as the group of outer automorphisms of $A$?" is potentially interesting and is about group equality rather than isomorphism, but it's *really* a question about what's going on inside the full automorphism group; and we don't care how exactly *that's* implemented in set theory.

**It is almost never useful to work with specific set-theoretic implementations of structures.** That doesn't mean set-theoretic implementation is pointless, just that it's relevant in a different way: it's a useful tool in proving global results (e.g. "every group ...") by telling us that we can apply coarse theorems about sets to ("small") mathematical structures in general.

Comment: @NoahSchweber.Thanks for your answer. I've edited my post  in order to make my last question a bit more explicit.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames I've edited to address that.